# How to organise application state in redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Imagine i had three main parts in my react application whose state is managed entirely by redux (no local state). `Login`, `Register` and `View Profile`:

My understanding is that the initial state would look like so:

```
const initialState = {
  login: {},
  register: {},
  profile: {},
  appUI: {
    menuToggled: false
  }
};


export function mainReducer(state = initialState, action) {
...
```

Then in my container component i would pull the relevant part of state using react-redux `connect()`:

```
function select(state) {
  return {
    state: state.login
  };
}

export default connect(select)(Login);
```

So when user types in username,password ..etc in the presentational component of login, the global state would be updated (using actions) and would end up looking like so:

```
{
  login: {
    username: "foo",
    password: "bar"
  },
  register: {},
  profile: {},
  app: {
    menuToggled: false
  }
};
```

Is this a valid approach? By valid i mean the way in which i am organising the state of my application, so if there were more "section" to the application as its growing (think crud) i would have greater number fields in the redux. I am new to react and redux and want to avoid any anti-patterns.

Comment: I don't think it's safe to keep the password in the store, no?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not an anti-pattern. The entire purpose of `mapStateToProps` - the first parameter in `connect` - is to extract the part of the application state, that the component needs.

The one thing that concerns me though is that your container component depends on something like login credentials. Also, I do not know how you have structured your reducer, but I would recommend using the [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) function from `redux`.